# node.js exec unable to find file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get some information about an image with GraphicsMagick, executing a child process with node.js Exec, here is the code:

```
var execGm= require('child_process').execFile;
var child;
child = execGm('gm identify /path/to/my/image/file/test.tif',
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
if (error !== null) {
  console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

in the node log I get this result : `stdout: stderr: exec error: Error: spawn ENOENT`.
If I execute the command `gm identify /path/to/my/image/file/test.tif` directly from the console in my MAC I get all the informations from the image. It's seems to me that the gm executable can't find the file, because with `child = execGm('gm',etc....` node return this log:

```
  stdout: GraphicsMagick 1.3.19 2013-12-31 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
  Copyright (C) 2002-2013 GraphicsMagick Group.
  Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
  See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.
  Usage: gm command [options ...]

  Where commands include: 
  batch - issue multiple commands in interactive or batch mode
  benchmark - benchmark one of the other commands
  compare - compare two images
  composite - composite images together
  conjure - execute a Magick Scripting Language (MSL) XML script
  convert - convert an image or sequence of images
  help - obtain usage message for named command
  identify - describe an image or image sequence
  mogrify - transform an image or sequence of images
  montage - create a composite image (in a grid) from separate images
  time - time one of the other commands
  version - obtain release version

  stderr: 
  exec error: Error: Command failed: `
```

I tried several paths but none works ...

Comment: `child = execGm('gm', [ 'identify', '/path/to/my/image/file/test.tif'], ...`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from @alexeyten, some properly formatted arguments were missing,

`child = execGm('gm', [ 'identify', '/path/to/my/image/file/test.tif'], ...`